# How do I make Cancel Token work on unMount

Tags: reactjs, cancellation-token

I'm trying to cancel a call that runs in intervals once I leave the screen it is called in. I trying to use a CancelToken on Unmount but it doesn't really do anything. It doesn't throw any errors either so I cannot really tell what is wrong. Here' the code

```html
export class App extends React.Component {
  private cancelToken!: CancelTokenSource;
  state: any = {}
  
  componentDidMount() {
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.cancelToken?.cancel();
  }
  
  private fetchSth(): void {

    const intervalNotExist = true

    if (intervalNotExist) {
      const newInterval = setInterval(() => {
        this.props.api!.fetchSth(nr, this.cancelToken).then(response => {
          if (!response.data) {
          }
        });
      }, 10000);
    }
  }
```

The fetch method is in my Api component:

```html
import axios, { AxiosInstance, CancelTokenSource } from 'axios';

export class Api {

private axiosGet(url: string, cancelToken ? : CancelTokenSource): Promise < any > {
  return this.axiosInstance.get(url, cancelToken && {
    cancelToken: cancelToken ? .token
  });
}

public fetchSth(nr: number, cancelToken : CancelTokenSource): Promise < any > {
  return this.axiosGet(`result/sth/get/${nr}`, cancelToken);
}

public cancelTokenHandler(cancelToken: CancelTokenSource | undefined) {
  if (cancelToken !== undefined) {
    cancelToken.cancel('Operation canceled due to new request.');
  }
  cancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source();
  return cancelToken;
}
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Can you just not `clearInterval(newInterval)` on unMount? This will clear the `setInterval` so the fetch function won't run after that.

Comment: Yes, that was my first approach, hovever newInterval is available only inside this function so you cannot call it outside. If you declare it outside and change const newInterval = setInterval to this.interval... it will indeed work, but ifyou enter the screen again the request will only fire once. Thats why it turned to cancel token